# List index out of range in 2d array

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a code in Python 3 which plays the game of fifteen. I'm currently working on the function to move a tile, but I can't seem to move on. Here is what my function looks like now:

```
def move(tile, d, board):
    for r in range(d):
        for c in range(d):
            if tile == board[r][c]:
                if board[r][c + 1] == "00":
                    # execute a swap algorithm
                if board[r][c - 1] == "00":
                    # execute a swap algorithm
                if board[r - 1][c] == "00":
                    # execute a swap algorithm
                if board[r + 1][c] == "00":
                    # execute a swap algorithm
    return False
```

d is the dimension here of the board which the user provides, for example the user types 4, the board will be a 4x4 square with the numbers 00 - 15 in it.
What I'm trying to accomplish here is to check if the value of the list to the right, left, bottom or top is equal to the two zeroes, because that's how I coded it, I will change it after I'm done. When I run my program it prints the board, but as soon as I type in a command that triggers the move function, I get 
this error:

```
 08 07 06
 05 04 03
 02 01 00
Tile to move: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fifteen.py", line 58, in <module>
    if move(tile, d, board) == False:
  File "fifteen.py", line 30, in move
    if board[r + 1][c] == "00":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In `for r in range(d)`, `r` iterates over values from `0` to `d-1`. So when `r` equals `d-1`, `r + 1` will give you `d`, which is out of range. You have to check whether `r + 1` is within bounds. Same goes for every `if` statement in your code.

Try something like:

```
def isWithinBounds(x, lower, upper):
    return x >= lower and x < upper
```

where lower = 0 and upper = dimension of board.